# How to avoid toc() printing the time elapsed in Julia?

Tags: julia

This might be a really stupid question, but I'll go ahead anyway. I'm trying to use Julia's `tic()` and `toc()` inside a loop in order to figure out some timing issues. A dummy example is shown below:

```
elapsedTime = zeros(3);

for i = 1:3
    tic();
    pause(i)
    ElapsedTime[i] = toc();
end
```

The goal is to store the elapsed time intervals in the array `ElapsedTime`. The issue is that `toc()` seems to **a)** print the elapsed time to screen and **b)** store it as wanted.

Is there some simple trick to avoid **a)**, ie. that `toc()` prints the result? It's not a huge problem, just annoying if the number of iterations is large.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried Julia's profiler?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

there is another version of toc() called toq() which doesn't print a thing and returns the elapsed time.

Answer (score 9):

You'll want the `@elapsed` macro.

```
elapsedTime = zeros(3);

for i = 1:3
  elapsedTime[i] = @elapsed sleep(i)
end
```

Comment: Add if the code to be measured is more than one command, you can do

    `elapsedTime[i] = @elapsed begin
        code here ...
    end`

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is probably a better way of doing what I asked for. I accepted the answer above since it is the simplest fix to my problem, but upvoted this as well. Will definitively look more into Julia's macros.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you could take the time manually and store it in the array>

```
elapsedTime = zeros(3);

for i = 1:3
    t1 = time_ns()
    rand(10000000)
    t2 = time_ns()
    elapsedTime[i] = (t2 - t1)/1.0e9
end
```

Comment: This works, but I think the two answers above are easier solutions to my problem. Thanks a lot anyway!